# jquery image map and multiple selectors

Tags: jquery

Morning all, am just about finished with an image map page I am working on...
What I am running into is the section of the map that will have multiple selectors.  YOu can see my example here. In the "dual" regions where 2 colors are visible, I am unable to get the two regions to highlight in the logo list to the right.

How can I get multiple selectors to be clickable in this map?

The section I am working on lies here:

```
$("#CarePointSAHAIDID").click(function() {  //use a class, since your ID gets mangled
    $("li.carepoint,li.saha,li.idid").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");      //add the class to the clicked element
  });
```

I want the Area  to highlight all 3 areas on the map, but they are also clickable from other areas as well...

https://jsfiddle.net/yd54vrcs/6/

Comment: Sorry Sherrif... never posted a jsfiddle link before... wasnt sure what the rules were

Comment: No worries. Thank you for fixing the jsfiddle link problem.